# Response.Redirect() target in to a div

Tags: asp.net

Can i redirect a page into a div using Response.Redirect()?

Comment: What do you mean "into a div", you mean "focus" on that div? Well that's easy, use an an anchor tag, specify the anchor in the URL - e.g Response.Redirect("somePage.htm#someanchor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a `<div>` exists client side. With a redirect you can only say that the current request should be submitted again at the new address. You can't specify where that redirect should end (frame, iframe, div, window ..).

You will have to do it from the client side: have the div (or whatever) load from some url (which could do a redirect).

Answer (score 0):

Whtr u need to display div on the same page or div on the another page? Or u want to display the particular div in a pop-up?

Comment: in the same page... inside that an iframe also there

Comment: K B:please add this as comment not answer